# Calling Physical Path Credentials for Web Applications in IIS

Tags: iis, powershell, windows-server-2012, web-applications

How would I call on the Physical Path credentials property for web applications in IIS using PowerShell? I can't print out the username or password, but I can print the `logonMethod` which uses the same property? Below is my code for web applications. I have tried using `$webapp.virtualDirectoryDefaults` and using `$webapp.userName` but neither works for web applications.

```
   $webapps = Get-WebApplication -Site $Site.name
   foreach($webapp in $webAPPS)
   {
       Write-Host $webapp.applicationPool
       Write-Host $WebApp.virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName
       Write-Host $webapp.virtualDirectoryDefaults.password
       Write-Host $webapp.virtualDirectoryDefaults.logonMethod
       $webapp2 = $webapp.path
       Write-Host $WebApp2.split("/")[-1] "::: is the Web Application" -ForegroundColor Green
   }
```

Comment: If the logon credentials for the physical path is set explicitly on the vDirs, then `$WebApp.virtualDirectoryDefaults.userName` and `.password` will be empty. You'll need to grab it from the individual vDirs

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen But wont that give the virtual directory physical path username and password instead of the web application username and password?

Comment: Strange, the credentials for the Application itself does not seem to get exposed by the object returned from `Get-WebApplication`. 

Would pulling it directly from the `applicationHost.config` file be an acceptable solution? The password would be encrypted and non-transferable

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen If we can call all web applications username/password in IIS that'd would be awesome! Just weird that I can call on the logonMethod object but not the username/password object for web applications, when the object exists there and gives you the automatic fill for username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still stuck on this the information is stored in a virtual directory object inside the application object in the applicationHost.config file.

This is a lot clearer in the newer IISAdministration modules.

I've put some code samples here on how to get the information using the WebAdministration module.

https://david-homer.blogspot.com/2024/03/solved-get-connect-as-credentials-for.html